# retrieve amount from database flask

Tags: python, flask, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a stripe checkout but when I tried to get the amount from the database or store amount in session, the checkout does not redirect to stripe checkout page.

```
    results=Cart.query.filter_by(username = current_user.username, session_id = session['coded'])
    total = sum([cart.amount for cart in results])
```

But if i replace total with integer, it works. The query is very accurate. Whats wrong?

```
@posts.route('/checkout')
def checkout():
    results=Cart.query.filter_by(username = current_user.username, session_id = session['coded'])
    total = sum([cart.amount for cart in results])
    
    session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        payment_method_types=['card'],
        line_items=[{
          'price_data': {
            'currency': 'usd',
            'product_data': {
            'name': 'T-shirt',
            },
            'unit_amount':  total,
          },

            #'price': 'price_1GznR1BlIKnRHDeI80wgnj0A',
            'quantity': 1,
        }],
        mode='payment',
        success_url=url_for('posts.processing', _external=True) + '?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
        cancel_url=url_for('posts.viewcart', _external=True),
    )
```

[image]

Comment: don't you get error message when you run in console/terminal? Did you use `print()` to check what you get in viarlabless ?

Comment: yea i did.....but in the console it shows error the terminal... i have uploaded the error in the question

Comment: error explain all - if you want to assign (`session = ...`) to external variable then you have to use `global` to inform function that it has to assign to external variable and not create local variable.

Answer (score 1):

I declared session as global. I ensured the amount is an integer

```
@posts.route('/checkout')
def checkout():
    global session
    results=Cart.query.filter_by(username = current_user.username, session_id = session['coded'])
    #results=Cart.query.filter_by(username = current_user.username, session_id = session['coded']).all()
    total = int(sum([cart.amount for cart in results]))

    print(results)
    session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        payment_method_types=['card'],
        line_items=[{
          'price_data': {
            'currency': 'usd',
            'product_data': {
            'name': 'T-shirt',
            },
            'unit_amount':  total,
          },

            #'price': 'price_1GznR1BlIKnRHDeI80wgnj0A',
            'quantity': 1,
        }],
        mode='payment',
        success_url=url_for('posts.processing', _external=True) + '?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
        cancel_url=url_for('posts.viewcart', _external=True),
    )

    return jsonify(checkout_session_id=session['id'], checkout_public_key=current_app.config['STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute your query:

```
    results=Cart.query.filter_by(username = current_user.username, session_id = session['coded']).all()
```